# using ZMV to replace all underscores to spaces recursively

Tags: regex, zsh

I'm trying to use zmv to replace "_" with " " and I cannot figure it out.  I then need to replace to spaces with one space.  This is for all files and folders.  I have found 50 references to how to change spaces to underscores but not the inverse.

Answer (score -1):

You can replace any number of underscores to single space using zmv like this:

```
zmv -n '(*_*)' '${1//( # ##_#|_##)/ }'
```

This will rename all files in current directory. If you want recursive rename (match files inside of directories), you can use this command instead:

```
zmv -n '(**/)(*_*)' '$1${2//( # ##_#|_##)/ }'
```

Be sure to check what will be done (`-n` parameter) before you run any of this, as there may be multiple files mapping into one file name.